# How to update date in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

My code looks like this

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("library", $con);

$colid = $_POST['data'];
$count = count($colid);
$curdate = date('Y-m-d');
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$tsql ="UPDATE transaction 
       set return=$curdate
       status='1'
       WHERE tid = $colid[$i] ";

$tresult = mysql_query($tsql);
}
if(! $tresult )
{
die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted book successfully\n";
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

and i get this error

```
Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'return=2014-04-21 status='1' WHERE tid = 1' at line 2
```

my requirement is that when ever i got clicked a button i need execute this code

i also tried using `CURDATE()` function getting the same error

any help would be appreciated

Comment: stop using mysql https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: I would also rather quote the date-String, so set `\`return\`="$curdate"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***Return***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) is a mysql reserved keyword you need to wrap it with back-ticks,and also a missing `comma` before  status pointed by [@user3414693](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3414693/user3414693)

```
UPDATE transaction 
       set `return`=CURDATE(),
       status='1'
       WHERE tid = $colid[$i]
```

Comment: also PHP needs date data to be enclosed in single quote uless mysql functions are used for current date now etc.

Comment: Added the comma word as it was missing!

Comment: @Abhik what? this is sql, not php

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i have used `CURDATE()` instead of `$curdate`

Comment: Yeah I meant using PHP varibales in sql needs to be quoted for dates else it will not update. set ` return `='$curdate'

Answer (score 3):

You missed a `comma ,` in your update. Also try to wrap `return` in `back ticks` as it is a **reserved keyword** in MYSQL. Try this:-

```
UPDATE transaction 
   set `return`=$curdate,    <-- here
   status='1'
   WHERE tid = $colid[$i] "
```

Comment: @user3414693 i have leveled the votes +1